# Conversion failed while using ids "where ID in (...)", nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in MSSQL 2008 like:

```
IF OBJECT_Id('tempdb..#AccessibleFacilities') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #AccessibleFacilities
SELECT u.Userid
     , AccesibleFacilityIds = dbo.GetCommaDelimitedString(upf.Facility_Id)  
INTO #AccessibleFacilities   
FROM Users u
INNER join UserProfileFacilities upf on upf.UserProfile_Id = up.Id  
WHERE LOWER(u.Userid) = LOWER(@userId)
GROUP BY u.Userid
```

This query returns AccessibleFacilityIds like `",1,2,3,4,5,6,"`. Please note that I am not able to modify GetCommaDelimitedString function.

What I actually need to do is that using those facility ids to reach provs like below:

```
INSERT INTO #AccessibleProvs
    SELECT Userid = @userId
         , AccessibleProvIds = dbo.GetCommaDelimitedString(distinct p.Id) 
    FROM Provs p 
         inner join ProvFacs pf on p.Id = pf.Provider_Id
    WHERE pf.Facility_Id in 
          (select a.AccesibleFacilityIds from #AccessibleFacilities a)
```

However, it gives me an error like:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ',1,2,3,4,5,6,'
>   to data type int.

I tried removing the comma signs at the start and end like below to fix it, but it did not help:

```
...
where pf.Facility_Id in (
      select SUBSTRING(a.AccesibleFacilityIds,2,LEN(a.AccesibleFacilityIds)-2) 
      from #AccessibleFacilities a
     )
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show sample data.  Using a CSV string in your query generally has a bad smell.

Comment: Since you can't modify the comma string function, can you make a new one? That would be way better than whatever parsing and replace operation you're going to get as an answer. CSV in a column is usually a sign of poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting `Facility_Id` into a comma delimited string, why not keep it as a usable column in your temp table?

```
if object_Id('tempdb..#AccessibleFacilities') is not null drop table #AccessibleFacilities;
select 
    u.UserId
  , upf.Facility_Id
into #AccessibleFacilities
from Users u
  inner join UserProfileFacilities upf 
    on upf.UserProfile_Id = up.Id
```

Then use it as you did with `in()` or with `exists()`:

```
insert into #AccessibleProvs
select 
    UserId = @userId
  , AccessibleProvIds = dbo.GetCommaDelimitedString(distinct p.Id) 
from Provs p 
  inner join ProvFacs pf 
    on p.Id = pf.Provider_Id
where exists (
   select 1
   from #AccessibleFacilities a
   where a.Facility_Id = pf.Facility_Id
     --and a.UserId = @UserId -- Do you need to check Facility_Id by User?
   )
```

If you have the value for `@UserId` in the beginning, you could limit your temp table usage to just the user you need. Hopefully this code is not meant for use in some sort of cursor or other loop.